# Convert string timestamp to comparable time in python

Tags: python, performance, datetime, comparison

Hi I'm trying to convert a string timestamp with this format ( 2/22/13 3:47:18:509 EST) to a comparable time object.

The problem is that I have a huge list (+50000 items) of timestamps (In ascending order) that I have to iterate and compare, but converting each item in the list is slow.

I need to extract the items from the list within a range of time (Actual time - N hours).

How could I do this efficiently?

Regards.

Note:

This is how I'm converting the date to a datetime object:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(_list[-1][2],  "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f %Z")
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '3/20/13 15:12:03:762 EDT' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f %Z'
```

EDIT: If I use hardcoded EDT in the expresion instead of %Z it works (But I need EDT and EST)

Comment: I think your error is that %f expects 6 characters, not that that is your main question.

Comment: @dwxw I already tested that but doesn't work: ValueError: time data '2/22/13 10:23:28:825000 EST' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f %Z'

Comment: Strangely, I just tried your example (with `'3/20/13 15:12:03:762 EDT'`) and it works for me

Comment: Had a play, and it didn't work for me. But @Nucklear the problem I see is strptime not liking the timezone 'EDT', remove that and it works fine. I would look at the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library for help with that bit.

Comment: python's `datetime` doesn't provide implementation for timezones, that's provided by external libraries like [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) or [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil). For parsing timezone aware datetime strings, you may want to look into [dateutil.parser.parse()](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2)